# Angular RxJs AutoRefresh Component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am working on an Angular 8 application. There is a requirement to auto refresh component every 5 sec.
I have used the below code.

refresh.componenet.ts:

```
import { Observable, Subscription, interval } from 'rxjs';
.
.
listStudents$: Observable<StudentModel[]>;
private updateSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(
    private listStudentsService: ListStudentsService
  ) { }

ngOnInit(): void{
    this.GetStudentsBySubject();        
  }

private GetStudentsBySubject() {    
    this.updateSubscription = interval(5000).subscribe((val) => {
      this.listStudents$ = this.listStudentsService.getStudentsBySubject(this.subject);      
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.updateSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

The above code works perfectly and refreshes component every 5 sec.

The component gets students list in `ngOnInit()`. Then it refreshes the data every 5sec. But the issue is that, the component waits 5sec to load the data for the first time also.

How can I conditionally set the auto refresh in this component to refresh every 5sec without waiting for the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous answers both work, however I would like to elaborate a bit more.

It's not a good idea to reassign your `listStudents$` continuously, as you'll create leaks this way.
Also the `updateSubscription` class member is unnecessary and makes it so you have a lot more to think about when cleaning up.

```js
import { Observable, Subscription, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { share , mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...
...
listStudents$: Observable<StudentModel[]>;

constructor(
    private listStudentsService: ListStudentsService
  ) { }

ngOnInit(): void{
    this.listStudents$ = timer(0,5000).pipe(
      mergeMap(()=>this.listStudentsService.getStudentsBySubject(this.subject)),
      share(), 
    );        
  }
}
```

`listStudents$` is now a "warm" observable.

Comment: Thank you. This is what exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can use timer which is another function of rxjs. It is used with an initial delay and a period.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html

```
this.updateSubscription = timer(0, 5000).subscribe((val) => { ...
```

Comment: it look the time operator is shortcut to my answer  ,and more cleaner  , good one

Answer (score 1):

you can use `startWith` operator

```
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

private GetStudentsBySubject() {    
    this.updateSubscription = interval(5000).pipe(startWith(0)).subscribe((val) => {... });
}
```

[**startWith**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html)